# Listing grid cell numbers for outlet according to flow direction using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, direction, flow

I am trying to list grid cell numbers whose flows contribute to the red cell I draw in the figure according to the known flow directions. Directions and colors are shown in the figure.

What tool can I use to list these grid cell numbers?

[image: Flow Directions and gridcell numbers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the watershed tool in ArcMap. After creating watershed with my flow direction file according to my pour point, I used the intersection tool to obtain point numbers that are inside the watershed area. Watershed area maybe has to be exported as a raster to use intersection tool.